# Jquery ui tabs - Why ui tabs wrapped by 'li' tag?

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs

Jquery ui tabs - Why ui tabs  wrapped by 'li' tag, instead put all in 'a' tag without add 'li' tag?

ui tabs design:

```
<ul>
<li>
<a></a>
</li>
<li>
<a></a>
</li>
</ul>
```

Why not just:

```
<div>
<a></a>
<a></a>
</div>
```

The cases demos on: http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/

**The html code of demo:**

```
<ul class="ui-tabs-nav ui-helper-reset ui-helper-clearfix ui-widget-header ui-corner-all">
        <li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top ui-tabs-selected ui-state-active"><a href="#tabs-1">Nunc tincidunt</a></li>
        <li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top"><a href="#tabs-2">Proin dolor</a></li>
        <li class="ui-state-default ui-corner-top"><a href="#tabs-3">Aenean lacinia</a></li>
    </ul>
```

---

**Update:**

article why its bad to add tags:
http://www.apaddedcell.com/div-itis

Thanks, Yosef

Answer (score 4):

Part of this is semantics. This is an unordered list of links, so it seems reasonable to use the `<ul>` (unordered list) and `<li>` (list item) setup. It's more meaningful than a generic `<div>`, which has no semantic value.

Additionally, having the extra block elements to wrap the inline elements may be easier to style in their case than single `<a>` tags behaving as blocks.

Comment: but it makes the html more nested like table design, and more complicate for search engines

Comment: @Yosef: the issue with table design wasn't that there was more markup, but that the markup was not being used in a meaningful way. The example of table design is actually an argument for the `<ul>` style. As far as search engines go, more semantic markup actually *helps* search engines like Google understand that it is a list of links, whereas links randomly scattered in a `<div>` may or may not be particularly meaningful.

Comment: soo why needed a tag if you already you have li tag or a tag have some special features for ui tabs?

Comment: @Yosef: first off, remember that the concept of [semantic HTML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_HTML) isn't *required*, per se. `<div>` and `<a>` will definitely cut it. However, it might be worth reading up on the concept of semantic markup and getting a feel for why people think it's worth their time. For me, it makes things more organized, and makes my code make more sense both to me and outsiders.